# In google sheets, GROUP BY variable and count unique values

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have a table for which my goal is to compute basic summary statistics on one column by group. The formula works great for all the statistics, but not for unique count:

```
=QUERY('C21:Q1853, "SELECT F, MIN(H), MAX(H), MAX(I), COUNT(M) WHERE F <> '' GROUP BY F")
```

This produces the results I am looking for. On the other hand, the formula below generates an error

```
 =QUERY('C21:Q1853, "SELECT F, MIN(H), MAX(H), MAX(I), COUNT(M), COUNTUNIQUE(M) WHERE F <> '' GROUP BY F")
```

Error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 46. Was expecting one of:  "where" ... "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ... "," ... "*" ... "+" ... "-" ... "/" ... "%" ... "*" ... "/" ... "%" ... "+" ... "-" ...

I have also tried using `COUNT(DISTINCT M))`.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: your first and last quote don't match

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet, that demonstrates the issue you're facing along with your desired result. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a syntax error in the GROUP BY, you might need to add a comma after F.

**Give this a try:**

```
=QUERY('C21:Q1853, "SELECT F, MIN(H), MAX(H), MAX(I), COUNT(M), COUNTUNIQUE(M) WHERE F <> '' GROUP BY F,")
```